# iw not finding wlan2

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I've a dwlink dwi-131 usb wifi adapter that I'm trying to use with buildroot (for a sama5d2xplained board) for hostadp.

I use a driver from github:
https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

The driver works and I can successfully connect to my AP. But setting up hostapd on the device itself fails. I suppose this is because the physical network device is not found by iw. However it is found by ip, iwconfig and ipconfig.

How can I debug this?

```
# uname -a
Linux buildroot 4.9.30-linux4sam_5.6 #1 Wed Aug 16 12:59:06 CEST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
# ifconfig -a
can0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          NOARP  MTU:16  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:39 

can1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          NOARP  MTU:16  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:50 

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FC:C2:3D:02:EC:32  
          inet addr:192.168.0.109  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:924 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1147892 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:37366 (36.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:30 Base address:0x8000 

hwsim0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 12-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:00:00:00:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:00:00:01:00  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:2A:A2:A7:0D:C8  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

# iwconfig 
wlan1     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

sit0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on

can0      no wireless extensions.

wlan2     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

hwsim0    no wireless extensions.

can1      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.


# cat /etc/hostapd.conf 
interface=wlan2
driver=nl80211
ssid=myssid
hw_mode=g
channel=1
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=secret
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
# hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd.conf 
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: TDLS external setup
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:10
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:8
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:9
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:13
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:11
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:12
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities mask (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=1
nl80211: Supported vendor event: vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=1
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: TDLS external setup
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:10
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:8
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:9
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:13
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:11
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:12
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=1
nl80211: Supported vendor event: vendor_id=0x1374 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface wlan2 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 10 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 10 to mode 3: -19 (No such device)
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan2 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=10 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 10 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 10 to mode 2: -19 (No such device)
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x7f2e0)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x7f2e0)
wlan2: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlan2
wlan2: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x80110 (wlan2))
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan2 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=(nil) drv_priv=(nil) -> hapd_deinit
hostapd_interface_free(0x7f2e0)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x80110
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x7f2e0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x7f2e0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x7f2e0
# 
Wiphy phy1
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2243 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Device supports T-DLS.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:10)
        * GCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:8)
        * GCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:9)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
        * CMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:13)
        * GMAC-128 (00-0f-ac:11)
        * GMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:12)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x1072
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX Greenfield
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x1072
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX Greenfield
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        VHT Capabilities (0x038007fa):
            Max MPDU length: 11454
            Supported Channel Width: 160 MHz, 80+80 MHz
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            short GI (160/80+80 MHz)
            TX STBC
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: MCS 0-9
            5 streams: MCS 0-9
            6 streams: MCS 0-9
            7 streams: MCS 0-9
            8 streams: MCS 0-9
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: MCS 0-9
            5 streams: MCS 0-9
            6 streams: MCS 0-9
            7 streams: MCS 0-9
            8 streams: MCS 0-9
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_config
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * tdls_mgmt
         * tdls_oper
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * testmode
         * channel_switch
         * set_qos_map
         * connect
         * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ IBSS } <= 1, #{ managed, AP, mesh point, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 2048, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, radar detect widths: { 20 MHz (no HT), 20 MHz, 40 MHz, 80 MHz, 160 MHz }

    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports AP scan.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Device supports active monitor (which will ACK incoming frames)
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports dynamic SMPS
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Device supports VHT-IBSS.
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2243 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Device supports T-DLS.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:10)
        * GCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:8)
        * GCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:9)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
        * CMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:13)
        * GMAC-128 (00-0f-ac:11)
        * GMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:12)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x1072
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX Greenfield
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x1072
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX Greenfield
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        VHT Capabilities (0x038007fa):
            Max MPDU length: 11454
            Supported Channel Width: 160 MHz, 80+80 MHz
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            short GI (160/80+80 MHz)
            TX STBC
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: MCS 0-9
            5 streams: MCS 0-9
            6 streams: MCS 0-9
            7 streams: MCS 0-9
            8 streams: MCS 0-9
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: MCS 0-9
            5 streams: MCS 0-9
            6 streams: MCS 0-9
            7 streams: MCS 0-9
            8 streams: MCS 0-9
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_config
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * tdls_mgmt
         * tdls_oper
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * testmode
         * channel_switch
         * set_qos_map
         * connect
         * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ IBSS } <= 1, #{ managed, AP, mesh point, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 2048, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, radar detect widths: { 20 MHz (no HT), 20 MHz, 40 MHz, 80 MHz, 160 MHz }

    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports AP scan.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Device supports active monitor (which will ACK incoming frames)
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports dynamic SMPS
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Device supports VHT-IBSS.
```

Comment: Try issuing, as sudo, the command: *iw list*. If, among the properties of your wifi-adapter, the is **no line** like: *software interface modes (can always be added): AP/VLAN*, then you are out of luck, your adapter cannot be used as an AP.

Answer (score 0):

> hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x80110 (wlan2)) hostapd_free_hapd_data:
>   Interface wlan2 wasn't started

Well, I've seen messages like this before, the reasons for this are usually:

- You have a hostapd service already runnig as daemon, search for the service `ps ax | grep hostap`

If it is runnig stop it

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hostapd stop
```

and then try runnig hostapd manually

```
sudo hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

- Your device is blocked, check `sudo rfkill list` ouput

If you see something like

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

run `sudo rfkill unblock wlan` 
If hard block is set to "yes" you should google a bit more, but the idea is that in the first place you should turn on the hardware switch

- Your device is managed by Network Manager, so remove it from managed Network Manager config as described [here](http://support.qacafe.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-prevent-network-manager-from-controlling-an-interface/)